# How to best safely use console.log and console.warn?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, cross-platform, ecmascript-5, console.log

I'm working to take over a code base that tests to make sure `console.warn` exists like this:

```
if (window.console) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  console.warn("shhaabang");                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

However, my problem with this is that it works only in the browser where you have a window object. This would seem to work too.

```
if (console && typeof console.warn == 'function') {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  console.warn("shhaabang");                                                                                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Are there any downsides to this method? Are there any better methods that don't assume the existence of `window`? Should I just see if window or global exists first and check both?

**CLARIFICATION** It should be obvious at the least that I'm testing this in something that doesn't have the `window` object. But, to be explicit **I am running this in node.js as well as the browser**

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a javascript logging framework that has already handed this rather than reinventing the wheel. For instance, try [loglevel](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel).

Here's how loglevel handles safe logging ([view full source](https://github.com/pimterry/loglevel/blob/master/lib/loglevel.js)):

```
function realMethod(methodName) {
    if (typeof console === undefinedType) {
        return false; // We can't build a real method without a console to log to
    } else if (console[methodName] !== undefined) {
        return bindMethod(console, methodName);
    } else if (console.log !== undefined) {
        return bindMethod(console, 'log');
    } else {
        return noop;
    }
}

function bindMethod(obj, methodName) {
    var method = obj[methodName];
    if (typeof method.bind === 'function') {
        return method.bind(obj);
    } else {
        try {
            return Function.prototype.bind.call(method, obj);
        } catch (e) {
            // Missing bind shim or IE8 + Modernizr, fallback to wrapping
            return function() {
                return Function.prototype.apply.apply(method, [obj, arguments]);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't do

```
if(console && typeof console.warn == "function"){ ... }
```

becuase this throws an error if console is not defined

you can use `this`

e.g.:

```
if(this.console){
  console.warn("shhaabang");
}
```

EDIT: oh sorry, i just noticed 2 things:
1) this does only work if `this` hasn't been changed... thanks @Evan Carroll
2) this does not work in `strict mode`, because in `strict mode`, `this` is `undefined`

so here's another approach:

```
var c;
try {
  c = console;
} catch(e){ 
  // console is not defined
}

if(c) {
  // console is defined
}else{
  // this will not throw because you declared `c` earlier
}
```